# Client - Server Connection Refused - Java

Tags: java, networking

I am learning networking programming. I have tried to implement a client server connection. However, I am encountering the error: **"Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)"**

I have tried changing the port from port 4999 to port 8080

Client Code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
    
     PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream()); 
     pr.println("is it working ");
     pr.flush();
    
     InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
     BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);
    
     String str = bf.readLine();
     System.out.println("server : " + str);

   }
 }
```

Server Code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
     ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);
     Socket socket = ss.accept();
     System.out.println("client connected");
    
     InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
     BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);
    
     String str = bf.readLine();
     System.out.println("client : " + str);
    
     PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
     pr.println("yes");
     pr.flush();
   }
}
```

Full Error:

```
~/test$ javac Client.java
~/test$ javac Server.java
~/test$ java Server
client connected
client : GET / HTTP/1.1
~/test$ java Client
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:231)
    at Client.main(Client.java:7)
```

I do not know why connection is being refused

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

The connection is refused because the server has terminated.
The code in `Server.java` reads one line, sends the response (`"yes"`) and then terminates.
Your output shows it printing `"GET / HTTP/1.1"` suggesting that something else (not your `Client` class) has hit port 8080, with a HTTP request (which is not unexpected for port 8080).
The server responds and then terminates, which returns you to the shell prompt.
Then when you run `java Client` there is no server running, and you see the connection error.
If you want the server to read multiple requests instead of terminating after one, you'll need a loop around everything from the `bf.readLine` to the `pr.flush`.

Comment: And then you'll need to use a separate terminal session to run the client.